# I need to create a new c# file in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I want to create a new console in vs code using the dotnet core but it prompts this:

the error

[image: 1]

If you know how to bypass this or find another way to create a new console then please help.

Comment: looks like you already have files in that folder.

Comment: first you have to delete existing project in that destination or change the destination to create new project.

Comment: Please provide error messages as text, not as links to pictures of text.

Answer (score 0):

use `dotnet new console --force`